# Including WinDbg in the vsjitdebugger list

Tags: windows, debugging, postmortem-debugging

Is it possible to include WinDbg in the list of debuggers shown by vsjitdebugger when the latter is configured as the default debuuger in HKLM...\AeDebug?

Ideally I would like to be able to include a few more command-lines to the list of choices in vsjitdebugger that are available when a process encounters an unhandled exception: using DrWatson or using WinDbg to save a minidump for later inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be such an (undocumented) option, up until VS7. The interface was a tool called [vs7jit](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vsnet.debugging/browse_frm/thread/3678c5acc3944055?pli=1).

It was also discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/browse_thread/thread/475ecc21c30cb635/818bdd912773d457?q=Extending+vsjitdebugger#818bdd912773d457), and the other directions brought up there may still be valid - specifically, the John Robbins 'Debugger chooser' code.